# AppHarbor: Conditional web.config

Tags: appharbor

I'd like a different web.config when deployed on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) vs deployed to a local network machine.

In particular, I'd like to turn on Windows Authentication so I can get the current Windows username when on a Windows network but still allow Anonymous users to connect when on AppHarbor.

(Best solution I can think of use AppHarbor Configuration Setting, configure AppHarbor to allow writing to files, then rewrite the web.config on Application_Start. Ugly.)

Answer (score 2):

No need to re-invent the wheel, AppHarbor team has figured this out.

I think [Custom web.config transforms and merges](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/07/27/custom-web-config-transforms-and-merges) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. AppHarbor only runs the Release transform. This is okay if you can devote the Release transform to AppHarbor.

Comment: No longer the case. You can specify the transform to use using the 'Environment' setting.